# Is Equational Reasoning an application of Referential Transparency?

Tags: functional-programming

In various discussions of the merits of functional programming, the phrase [referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29) or [equational reasoning](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/12/equational-reasoning.html) is often listed.

My question is - **are these roughly the same thing?** (One being the concept, and the second being the process of applying the concept?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Referential transparency is an **operational notion**: it describes what happens when you **evaluate** a same piece of code (typically a function) several times, namely, the return value is the same. In particular, the **evaluation context** can generally be ignored when considering the operational semantics of a referentially transparent language.

Equational reasoning is, well, a way to **reason** about code: it allows you to replace pieces of code with others without worrying about things like evaluation order or current state. This is usually valid *because of referential transparency*; in general the value of a given code block is dependent on it's *context* which prevents replacing a piece of code by another *regardless* of it's position within another block.

In conclusion, referential transparency is a **property of the evaluation semantics** and the ability to do equational reasoning is a **benefit** of this property.